# There should be an indication that you can click on the badge being tracked under 'next badge'

Tags: feature-request, badge-progress

It's possible to click on the badge being tracked under 'next badge' for additional information:

[image: example of the Refiner badge being tracked]

[image: result of clicking on the badge, showing additional details]

There's no indication that this is possible. There should either be a 'pointer' cursor or the information should appear on hover.

Looking at the CSS, this could be a bug, but I'm not sure:

[image: CSS showing that the cursor is set to 'pointer', but then overridden and set to 'auto']

Comment: Well, by seeing this post, people will come to know about it ;)

Comment: A pointer cursor would seem the most in line with how badges are presented in other places on the same page.

Comment: Indeed sounds like an `!important` bug. (read it as you wish you CSS parser)

Comment: @Gourav You're right, I didn't know until now.

Comment: My .s-card doesn't have the cursor property?

Comment: @Braiam according to my browser the rule comes from https://cdn.sstatic.net/Shared/DevStory/story.css?v=5c13f296041d